# How to make a program wait until a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I was wondering how I could make my program wait until a certain button is pressed.

To illustrate my question, I have made a dummy WPF game where the user can roll two dices as long as he doesn't get double. The goal of the game is having the highest roll count.

I have the following 'Dice' class :

```
class Dice
{
    TextBlock diceTextBlock;

    const int minNumber = 1;
    const int maxNumber = 6;

    int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set
        {
            number = value;
            diceTextBlock.Text = number.ToString();
        }
    }

    public Dice(TextBlock diceTextBlock)
    {
        this.diceTextBlock = diceTextBlock;
        Number = minNumber;
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        Number = new Random().Next(minNumber, maxNumber + 1);
    }
}
```

I have also the following 'GameWindow' class :

```
public partial class GameWindow : Window
{
    Dice dice1;
    Dice dice2;

    int rollCount;

    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dice1 = new Dice(Dice1TextBlock);
        dice2 = new Dice(Dice2TextBlock);

        rollCount = 0;

        Play();
    }

    private void RollButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dice1.Roll();
        dice2.Roll();
        rollCount++;
    }

    private void Play()
    {
        do
        {
            //  Wait for the user to press the 'RollButton'
        }
        while (dice1.Number != dice2.Number);
    }
}
```

How do I make my program wait for the user to press the 'RollButton' in the 'Play()' method?

I have tried to learn about events and asynchronous programming. However, as a beginner, I have some difficulties to understand these concepts. Also, I am not sure that these can help to solve my problem.

Comment: I would consider a strategy that doesn't involve a do-while loop at all.  Instead, each time the roll button is run, check your exit condition then and perform any tasks associated with end of game if an only if your dice are equal.

The problem with the do-while design is Play is run in the constructor, which means the window never finishes construction and the user will never see it.  It just gets hung in an infinite loop.

Comment: Tip: Try not to pass the `Dice1TextBlock` instance to the `Dice` class. Next time you want to reuse the `Dice` class while putting the result in a `Label`. Use the `Number` property in your `GameWindow` class. It's not a problem to call a `UpdateTextBlock(TextBlock tb, newValue);` method.

Comment: The problem with the while loop is, that it blocks the UI thread, because it's stuk in your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

to make it understandable to you, you need to remove the `Play();` inside the GameWindow. Therefore you need to add `Play();` to the end of `RollButton_Click(...)` inside the brackets.
This should be easier than asynchronous programming especially if you just want to make a simple programme like this.
Also the do while loop does nothing, just make a bool method which checks whether dice 1 and 2 have the same numbers. If they have the same number you can return true to end the game and false if the don't have matching numbers.
Inside the method `RollButton_Click(...)` you Check whether the two numbers are matching or not. If they do you display the message that the two numbers matched and how many tries it took

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to wait asynchronously:

```
public partial class GameWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    Dice dice1;
    Dice dice2;

    int rollCount;

    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    public GameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dice1 = new Dice(Dice1TextBlock);
        dice2 = new Dice(Dice2TextBlock);

        rollCount = 0;

        Loaded += async (s,e) => await PlayAsync();
    }

    private void RollButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dice1.Roll();
        dice2.Roll();
        rollCount++;
        semaphore.Release();
    }

    private async Task PlayAsync()
    {
        //  Wait for the user to press the 'RollButton'
        do
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        }
        while (dice1.Number != dice2.Number);

        MessageBox.Show("Yes!");
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        semaphore.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        semaphore.Dispose();
    }
}
```